# Debug function in SQL Server 2008 that is invoked by triggers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, debugging

I have a situation where a (user-defined) function that is invoked by (legacy) triggers apparently calculates and enters a wrong value into a table. The problem surfaces e.g. when one `UPDATE`s the value, which then immediately reverts to another/wrong value, apparently because the function kicks in with a wrong calculation.

I am not yet familiar with the SQL Server's debugger. Can I e.g. set a breakpoint it the function such that execution will stop in the SF after launching the offending `UPDATE` and I can then inspect values and single-step. Is this possible and is there perhaps a good tutorial on this kind of scenario?

So far, I have tried this:

1. opened SF with "Modify"; set breakpoint in line with 'SELECT'
2. opened "New Query"; executed `UPDATE`

This did not work insofar as the reversion did not occur (`UPDATE` worked as if there were not triggers and SF was not invoked). Perhaps it is because the SF and query belong to different sessions or because I lack sufficient privileges. How can I make progress from this (or a better) starting point?

Comment: A common trick for debugging triggers (it's really old-school) is to just create tables (tablename_inserted, tablename_deleted) with an IDENTITY column in addition to all the other columns of tablename, and then in the trigger, modify it to insert the inserted and deleted collections into those tables.  That lets you see at your leisure exactly what is being passed into the trigger code, and you can then run modified trigger code in your own session against those tables to debug in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The [Transact-SQL Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645997.aspx) is not necessarily straight forward to setup and depending on your network arrangements may require firewall changes, see the online docs for complete info. The simplest arrangement is where you can use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) on the SQL Server machine.

Once you have the debugger working then put the breakpoint on the UPDATE statement and single-step into it.

Without using the debugger though debugging functions is tricky because T/SQL functions can not modify the database state; they can't use the PRINT or RAISERROR statements.